# What is the best way to reference other page to a visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

I want to include other VF page into my visualforce page, what is the best way to do that except using `iframe`?

Comment: Do you want to include another VF page or a external page ?

Comment: already edited my question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it would be to either:

1. Use `<apex:include>`

> A component that inserts a second Visualforce page into the current
>   page. The entire page subtree is injected into the Visualforce DOM at
>   the point of reference and the scope of the included page is
>   maintained.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_include.htm

2. Or if Appropriate create and use a visual force Component

> The body of an  tag is the markup that is added to a
>   standard Visualforce page whenever the component is included. For
>   example, the following Visualforce page uses the component defined in
>   Custom Component Markup (in this example, the component was saved with
>   the name myComponent)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_comp_cust_using.htm

**Caveat** for both of these: You cannot use a page or component using `<apex:form>` inside the parent page's `<apex:form>` tags.